# STM32: UART DMA does not start correctly

Tags: c, serial-port, stm32, uart, dma

I am using two STM32H743 connected via RS232. These two modules connected to same power.
They use UART with DMA. When I turn on modules at the same time, UART and DMA starts correctly.
But when i restart one of the modules while other is awake, the reset module's UART and DMA does not start therefore they cannot communicate with each other.
This problem is also happened before with STM32F4 series. MCU is connected to FPGA and they communicate via UART. When FPGA starts before MCU, DMA and UART does not start properly. What could cause this problem?
Do i need to have a high-z or floating pin states before starting UART?

Comment: If you are using HAL, then you should use the `HAL_UART_DeInit(huart)` in both sides to avoid any unexpected char to be received by one of the sides of the communication. I also had similar problem and turns out that when one of them is rebooting, any trash signal would trigger the other side as a start byte, and then the UART gets lost.

Comment: I also debugged further and found that error registers indicates frame error. Also when i unplugged rs232 cable without power down, MCU triggers a uart error callback (frame error). When i get this interrupt, i reinit the uart perhibral and it works again. But sometimes, not always, when MCU first initialize UART, it does not start and DMA does not carry any bytes. It is really interesting. Why it happens when first initialization, i could not find  the reason.

Comment: I have the impression that this is an electrical engineering problem, not a software problem. Please consider posting the question at [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) and removing it here.

Answer (score 3):

After lots of debugging hours, I finally found the cause and solution.
When first bytes reach to UART peripheral, due to clock mismatch, it triggers frame error then stops the DMA. This happens more than usual when UART datarate is very high. But I had added the ErrorCallback function to handle the interrupt. Unfortunately, I misused the function.

My use :

```
void HAL_UART_ErrorCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    HAL_UART_MspDeInit();   
    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(...);
}
```

HAL_UART_MspDeInit does not clear structs and initializations therefore Receive_DMA function cannot start it again. So, my communication stops.

Correct use :

```
void HAL_UART_ErrorCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    HAL_UART_DeInit();  
    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(...);
}
```

Thanks to three typos in my code, it caused to me a lot of time. But finally, it resolved.

Comment: I had something similar. Except your solution wouldn’t fix it correctly. My UART module after reset would be down for ~1 second, then come back online. If I deinit() and receive in the error handler, my ISR would be called thousands of times at nearly 100% CPU usage until the other side came up and it wasn’t detecting frame errors (mcu RX line low) anymore. My solution was to deinit uart in error ISR like you, then turn the UART RX line to an EXTI triggered on rising edge, in that EXTI ISR I reinit uart. I don’t bother retrying until I know the other side is online by seeing that line come up.

Answer (score 0):

The UART and DMA peripherals usually have an error detector, thus has it's flags into the status register. When an error happen, the STM32 HAL will stop any transfer ongoing and wait until you treat this fail. You can check, with the debug module, the HAL status registers to troubleshoot the problem, and add the treatment to it in you code. At first you could reset the peripheral by run DeInit() and right after run Init() routine of the peripheral with error, and reset any other piece of code e.g. state machines and stuff that uses the data from this peripheral.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the source of the problem is the HAL, which reacts to any error by disabling the DMA. As I use circular DMA that's not a viable way to handle errors. An error is also sure to happen while initializing while data streaming in (at speed), as you found out. Here's my solution, augmenting the usual `UART_Start_Receive_DMA()` init code:

```
// flush the UART, otherwise the DMA won't start with data coming in
RMA_USART->CR1 &= ~USART_CR1_RE;        // disable UART rx
while (USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE_RXFNE) {
    u8 h = USART1->RDR;                 // flush the FIFO
    UNUSED(h);
}
USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RE;            // reenable UART rx
// now race to setup the UART with DMA (as usual)
UART_Start_Receive_DMA(&huart1, (u8 *)my_rx.buf, sizeof(my_rx.buf));
// stop errors from aborting the DMA (can't do this in Cube)
__HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(&hdma_usart1_rx, DMA_IT_TC);
```

Please disable interrupts disabled while running this code.

A better solution would be replace the HAL code with something closer to the metal. I didn't try this, but [libopencm3](https://libopencm3.org) seems like it could be worthwhile.

Also note that DMA channel 3 can't be used for UART RX on at least some STM32.